# CS50 BULBS How can I turn my printF 0's and 1's into a variable that i can put into my printbulb function?

Tags: c, cs50

When I execute my program It prints the binary value for the individual character in a string you enter . How do I get that set of 0's and 1's in a variable that I can use in my void print_bulb(int bit) function. i just used a forloop to check for the remainder of the asci value / 2 and printed 0 for no reminder and 1 for a reminder then divided by 2 and and checked for the reminder again and kept going until my asci value was 0.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

const int BITS_IN_BYTE = 8;

void print_bulb(int bit);

int main(void)
{
    // TODO

    string l = get_string("enter a string\n");
    int a = strlen(l);

    for (int i =0; i < a; i++)
    {
        int c = l[i];

        for(int j = 0; j<8; j++)
            if ( c % 2== 0)
            {
                printf("0\n");
                int b = c / 2;
                c=b;
            }
            else if(c % 2 ==1)
            {
                printf("1\n");
                int b = c / 2;
                c=b;
            }
    }
}

void print_bulb(int bit)
{
    if (bit == 0)
    {
        // Dark emoji
        printf("\U000026AB");
    }
    else if (bit == 1)
    {
        // Light emoji
        printf("\U0001F7E1");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the value you're printing is the same as what you're comparing to, Just print the value of `c % 2`.

```
for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
    print_bulb(c % 2);
    c /= 2;
}
```

To print the bits from left to right, you can use bit shifting  insead of repeated divisions. When using bitwise operations you should use an unsigned value.

```
    for (int i =0; i < a; i++)
    {
        unsigned char c = l[i];

        for (int j = 7; j >= 0; j--) {
            print_bulb((c >> j) % 2);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is there a way I can print it right to left in stead of left to right. since binary starts counting on the right first.

Comment: this prints the bits from right to left. If you mean the characters, change the first lop to be `for (int i = strlen(l)-1; i >= 0; i--)`

Comment: Ok my bad I need to print left to right because im getting 00010010 for number 72 to binary but i need to get 01001000